# How many 2-digit positive integers are there?

Tags: number-theory, gre-exam

How many 2-digit positive integers are there such that the product of their two digits is 24?

The answer given is four. I'm not certain if I understand this question correctly and need some guidance on how to approach it the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get $24$ only from: $3\times 8, 4\times 6$. Thus, the only possible numbers are: $\boxed {38, 83, 46, 64} $.